# obtaining POST parameters at a URL passed through by DYNDNS

Tags: post, redirect, dns

**Background:**

Foobar.htm form uses this:

```
<form action="http://rawurl-here.gotdns.org" method="POST">
   [...]
</form>
```

rawurl-here.gotdns.org is a Dynamic DNS url that redirects the user to:

```
 http://currentsite001.mysite.org
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to ensure that the POST parameters sent by Foobar.htm always reach the final target, regardless of the passthru from rawurl-here.gotdns.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, POST requests cannot be redirected. The [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) says that any attempt to redirect a non-GET/HEAD request must be confirmed by the user. However, as noted in the text for the 302 redirect, most browsers ignore this and simply change the POST to a GET instead at which point your parameters are gone.

> rawurl-here.gotdns.org is a Dynamic DNS url that redirects

You need a dynamic DNS service that doesn't redirect, but just points the DNS A record directly to your IP address. Set your box up to respond to requests for `rawurl-here.gotdns.org` and now you don't need a redirect.

DNS redirect and framing services suck anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use DynDNS and haven't problems with POST data.

Do you have problems? Or just want ensure if the data are sent for your target?

[]'s,

And Past

Comment: Yes I have problems, the POST data does not seem to reach the page when I use the DYNDNS passthru, but when I send directly to the final URL, the POST data makes it through. I know because the page just does a CGI "dump".